# Get bounding box from Candelsticks series using Combo Chart in Google Charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, boxplot, candlestick-chart

I've just started to use Google Charts and it's just wonderful. Unfortunately (and surprisingly) it doesn't have a Box Plot in its repertory, so I decided to emulate it by adding a line on top of a Candlesticks chart (I'm using the Candlesticks as a series of a Combo Chart because I also need a Line Chart within the same plot).

Frustratingly I've tried to get the attributes of each box of the Candlesticks Chart by using the `getBoundingBox(id)` method, but I have no clue about how to specify the `id`.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#methods) say

> The format for `id` isn't yet documented (they're the return values of
>   [event handlers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events)), [...]

but I can't find any signs of how the *event handlers*' output might be.

How can I specify the `id` so that a single box of the Candlesticks Chart is returned?

```
// relevant part of the code
function drawChart() 
{
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        // data here
        ], true);

    var options = {
        vAxes: {
            0: {},
            1: {}, 
        },
        series: { 
            0: {
                type: "candlesticks", 
                targetAxisIndex: 0,
            },
            1: {
                type: "line",
                targetAxisIndex: 1,
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function()
    {
        var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
        var cries_in_the_corner = layout.getBoundingBox( /* useless attempt of id */ );

        console.log(cries_in_the_corner); // always 'null'
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the chart's `click` event to find the `'id'`

but it will look similar to this...

`'candlestick#0#0'`

where the first `0` is the series number, and the second `0` is the row number

see following working snippet, the properties of the chart element clicked will be displayed in the console...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
  ], true);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'CandlestickChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'click', function (gglClick) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(gglClick));
    });
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    chart.draw();
  });
  chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```